# When should user stories be combined and separated?

Tags: agile, user-story

As a school project, we are rolling out our initial set of user stories. Should a user story record the original idea from a user, without combining them or separate them?

For example, John added that "I want to post multiple choice questions.", and Mike added that "Except multiple questions, I want to post true/false questions." David added that "I want a confirmation box before I add questions"

Do you leave those 3 user stories as it is, or you want to combine John's and Mike's as "I want to post multiple choice and true/false questions." and within this new user story a detail like "show a conformation box before clicking the add buttion"?

What do you choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stories should ideally meet the INVEST criteria: Individual, Negotiable, Valuable, Estimable, Small, Testable. Choose story granularity to reflect what can be potentially delivered.

Can you add multiple choice questions separately from true/false questions? Can you allow submitting question even if there's not a confirmation box? Is a true/false question a special kind of multiple choice question (with the choices being true/false).

There doesn't have to be a mapping between what users say and the resulting user stories. If a user's idea includes multiple sub-ideas, then split that into separate stories. If a user's idea just elaborates another user's idea, then combine them into one user story.

I disagree with Kevin's answer that "Show a confirmation story" isn't a story, because it could be. It might be very reasonable to have just a "submit" button and then later add a confirmation step.